# Spring Ribbon @LoadBalanced doesn't work with @scope("prototype") for restTemplate

Tags: spring, resttemplate, netflix-ribbon

I'm following [the official spring ribbon guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/client-side-load-balancing/), and I noticed one thing.

If a `RestTemplate` is being created in this way :

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)  ---- I added this line
RestTemplate restTemplate(){
    logger.warn("create a restTemplate bean..."); --- added this for debug
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Then the ribbon client will not be able to find server. (unable to parse client name with server IP address);

I debugged into bean creation process, and noticed that the message, "create a restTemplate bean...", has appeared twice in the log.

And the auto wired restTemplate instance doesn't have a `LoadBalancerInterceptor`, which is probably why it fails.

So I wonder if there is any suggestion to fix this issue?

P.S: I need `RestTemplate` to be prototype so that I can set different errorHandlers.

Answer (score 1):

It really fails because of the missing LoadBalancerInterceptor, but the class can be simply injected.
Inject it, and take the @LoadBalanced annotation away:

`java
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    RestTemplate loadBalancedTemplate(LoadBalancerInterceptor loadBalancerInterceptor) {
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        template.getInterceptors().add(loadBalancerInterceptor);
        return template;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the [author](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48913657/2):

> It turns out that `@LoadBalanced` annotation won't retrieve a `RestTemplate` bean from the application context, with 'prototype' scope, it will simply retrieve a new instance, which is not used by any autowired field.